# Fiting uv map to image

Tags: uv

I want to create a wall for a castle .Lets say that the image i want to fit to that wall is 4x4 (meters). And my mesh is 1.8(lenght)x5.3(height) [also in meters].
[image]
I assumed that the uv area (i dont know what it is called , the one i circled) 
Is where the image is , which is 4x4 as mentioned.

So i smart unrapped it (stretch to uv bounds and correct aspect)
[image]
I also assumed that my uv unwrap is also 4v4 since my image fiting there was 4x4)
Pressed R: 90 ,  (for rotation) then S: .25 (to scale my object bounds to 1x1)
Then S: x 1.8 and S: y 5.3 to fit original size of mesh to image.[image] 
After that i did the same thing to another wall size 2.25x2.9 (meters) with the same picture and the result was that they had diffrent size of bricks. [image]

Pls i would apprieciate any help / tip . im kinda new . (the project is to exported to unity and im telling that cause of the nodes) . THanks in advance

*What im trying to say is , how to fit the same image to driffrent wall sizes, and keep image-brick size the same.

Comment: Please crop pictures before uploading them.  It is good practice to put effort into asking your question, it encourages others to put effort into their answer.

Comment: A good principle on uvmapping is marking manually marking seams. Usually this "stretching" issues doesn't happen if you manually unwrap after marking correctly the seams.

From blender documentation:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/seams.html

From tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k

Comment: @Moog Personally, I would rather that questioners *didn't* crop their pictures.  It is often the case that extra information contained in the margins (like on a properties viewport) speeds troubleshooting.  It's frequently the case that people with problems don't know what information to include, because the whole reason they're having a problem is that they don't know enough to know what the problem is.  Your perspective is totally valid; I'm just offering that it's not necessarily shared by everybody answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

what's up fellow beginner! Did you set the rotation and scale before unwrapping? In Object mode, select the Object and press **Ctrl+A.** Select **Apply > Rotation & Scale.** This is a helpful tip if you find your uv maps come out with weird aspect ratios.

Comment: Hallo mate . I 've just tried what u said , and both "walls" were in x.y.z=1 also rotation to 0 ,  and ti didnt seam to work.  (i cant upload a picture to show u im afraid , or dont know how :P ) .. here :https://files.fm/u/yda4s52p#/

Comment: Oh. Sorry then! But if you don't get your answer in a couple more days, there is always the emergency option that I use sometimes: hiring someone more knowledgeable to fix the problem from fiverr.com, lol. Good luck!